# AVERAGE to apply to a list of variable length, but only up to the row in which the formula resides

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average, worksheet-function

I have a column Column A where I will keep adding numbers to it. I want column B to show the average of numbers in column A but only up until that row

For example

```
B1  =AVERAGE(A1:A1)
B2  =AVERAGE(A1:A2)
B3  =AVERAGE(A1:A3)
```

Is there a formula that will accomplish this without me having to change the formula every time I add a number?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you mean something like:

```
=AVERAGE(A$1:A1)
```

copied down to suit.

Comment: Thank you but all that does is Average A2:A2, A3:A3 etc so it just shows the same number on Column A and Column B

Comment: @user2941841 notice the $ sign, it will keep the row 1 static in the formula so it will be an expanding range, it will not be A2:A2, A3:A3 but rather A1:A1, A1:A2, A1:A3 etc

Comment: This was the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Its called an absolute reference and is extremely handy for running totals and many other things, play around with it a bit, I am pretty sure you will quickly find loads of uses for it :). You can absolute column or row references, you can cycle through the absolute references by pressing F4 when editing a formula and your cursor is in a cell or range reference.

Comment: This is why I love working in R1C1 mode. The formula becomes `=AVERAGE(R1C[-1]:RC[-1])` (or even `=AVERAGE(R1C1:RC1)`) which I think is much easier to read than trying to figure out what the `$` does in A1 mode.

Comment: @pnuts - I've never got used to the `$`. Once I converted my thinking to R1C1 it is so much easier to get formulas correct. Even the most basic formula like `=G3` isn't particularly readable unless you know you are on `H3` - the R1C1 equivalent `=RC[-1]` immediately tells you that you are referencing the cell immediately to the left of the current cell. So much simpler IMHO.

Answer (score -3):

@user2941841 notice the $ sign, it will keep the row 1 static in the formula so it will be an expanding range, it will not be A2:A2, A3:A3 but rather A1:A1, A1:A2, A1:A3 etc –  Dan Donoghue 7 mins ago